# uncaught type error keeps increasing when I keep scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, scroll, typeerror

I have been working on this website project. I wrote a code to enable smooth scrolling on my website. But for some reason, I keep getting an error that increases anytime I scroll up or down. It's been a hurdle and any help will be greatly appreciated!

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
      
      //smoothscroll
      $('.scroll-to-section a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $(document).off("scroll");
          
          $('.scroll-to-section a').each(function () {
              $(this).removeClass('active');
          })
          $(this).addClass('active');
        
          var target = this.hash,
          menu = target;
          var target = $(this.hash);
          $('html, body').stop().animate({
              scrollTop: (target.offset().top) + 1
          }, 500, 'swing', function () {
              window.location.hash = target;
              $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
          });
      });
  });

  function onScroll(event){
      var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
      $('.nav li a').each(function () {
          var currLink = $(this);
          var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
          if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
              $('.nav ul li a').removeClass("active");
              currLink.addClass("active");
          }
          else{
              currLink.removeClass("active");
          }
      });
  }
```

I have attached a picture of the errors I have been getting:

[image: Error messages picture]

Kindly help please!

Comment: Your `onScroll` has -> `refElement.position().top `,  so `refElement.position()` is `undefined`

Comment: Also -> `$(currLink.attr("href"));`  not used jQuery for a long time, but what does creating a jQuery object on a `href` actually do?..   Oh, hang on just clicked, your `href` a re tagged hrefs's.. eg.. `href="#id"`

Comment: Would using [`getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) to get the position values such as `top` work "better"?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, the documentation for [`offset`](https://api.jquery.com/offset/) and [`position`](https://api.jquery.com/offset/) doesn't say this explicitly, but if you call them on a jQuery object that has no elements in it, they return `undefined`.

```js
console.log($(".no-element-matches-this").offset());
console.log($(".no-element-matches-this").position());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

So that's what's happening, you're calling `offset` or `position` on an empty jQuery object. To fix it, you'll have to see which call(s) it is and then handle the possibility that the object will be empty.

Given it's happening when you're scrolling, it seems likely to relate to your `onScroll` function's calls to `position`:

```
var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
if (refElement.position().top /*...*/)
```

So to fix it:

1. Determine if it's valid that `refElement` might have no matching elements in it.
2. **If** it's not valid, find out why it's happening and fix it.
3. If it **is** valid, add a guard.

#3 might look like:

```
const refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
if (!refElement.length) {
    // ...no matching elements, determine what you want to do...
} else {
    // No need to repeat calls to `position`
    const pos = refElement.position();
    if (pos.top <= scrollPos && pos.top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
        $(".nav ul li a").removeClass("active");
        currLink.addClass("active");
    } else {
        currLink.removeClass("active");
    }
}
```

or perhaps

```
const refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
const pos = refElement.position();
if (!pos) {
    // ...no matching elements, determine what you want to do...
} else {
    if (pos.top <= scrollPos && pos.top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
        $(".nav ul li a").removeClass("active");
        currLink.addClass("active");
    } else {
        currLink.removeClass("active");
    }
}
```

...but again, only if it's really valid that `$(currLink.attr("href"))` doesn't match any elements.